# Analisar request e decidir ação, extensão chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Como manipular uma request de url antes de abrir a pagina no google chrome?
Pesquisando eu achei como bloquear o request de uma url especifica, mas estou um pouco confuso com como manipular a url e redirecionar.

Exemplo bloqueando url do protetor de links `ouo.io`:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(detalhes) {
    return {cancel: detalhes.url.indexOf("://ouo.io/") != -1};
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Porém eu gostaria de manipular a URL em alguns casos, exemplo pegar a URL de um parâmetro e redirecionar: `?s=`

`http://ouo.io/s/1XTIn2cB?s=https://google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se `detalhes.url` retorna uma string exatamente como:

> ```
> http://ouo.io/s/1XTIn2cB?s=https://google.com
> ```

Você pode usar a API `URL` que é nativa, para manipular e extrair os dados específicos, como falei nesta resposta [**Para que serve $(this.hash) no jQuery?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387408/3635)

No seu caso usaremos o `URL.searchParams` para pegar o valor de `s=`, exemplo de uma string:

```js
var urlDaExtensao = 'http://ouo.io/s/1XTIn2cB?s=https://google.com';
var params = new URL(urlDaExtensao).searchParams;
var qValue = params.get('s');

console.log(qValue);
```

Veja que o `console.log` emitirá ao console o resultado, então poderia usar isto para redirecionar a aba atual com a propriedade [`redirectUrl`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#redirectUrl), ficando assim:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (detalhes) {
    if (detalhes.url.indexOf("://ouo.io/") != -1) {

        var urlDaExtensao = detalhes.url;
        var params = new URL(urlDaExtensao).searchParams;
        var qValue = params.get('s');

        //Se tiver um valor redireciona
        if (qValue) {
            return { "redirectUrl": qValue };
        } else {
            //Se não tiver o valor do direcionamento cancela a requisição
            return { "cancel": true };
        }
    } else {
        //Se for outra URL não cancela
        return { "cancel": false };
    }
}, {
    urls: [ "<all_urls>" ]
}, [ "blocking" ]);
```