# document.referrer para obter só apenas o domínio

Tags: javascript

Estou usando a instrução "document.referrer" para realizar algumas ações em meu website, porém, tenho percebido que em algumas situações, document.referrer preciso que ele exibir só apenas o dominio.com sem o https://

```
<script>document.write(document.referrer);</script>
```

Como posso resolver essa questão de referencia sem o https://

Qual seria a melhor solução para obter a referencia só apenas do domínio de onde meu site venho foi clicado de qual domínio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A interface URL()

Não é restrito ao refer(r)er, qualquer URL pode ser processado com a interface URL().

Veja um exemplo que exibe somente o hostname:

```js
var urlText = "https://example.com/path/to/resource.htm?query=string";

var urlObj = new URL(urlText);
console.log(urlObj.hostname);
```

#### Aplicado ao caso da pergunta:

Note que aqui é um ótimo exemplo, pois o JS e o `iframe` são executados em outro domínio, mas o `referer` vem com o site principal:

```js
var urlObj = new URL(document.referrer);
document.write(urlObj.hostname);
```

Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

#### Visualizando outras propriedades:

```js
var urlText = "https://name:secret@example.com:8081/path/to/resource.htm?query=string#target";

var urlObj = new URL(urlText);
console.log('protocol:' + urlObj.protocol);
console.log('username:' + urlObj.username);
console.log('password:' + urlObj.password);
console.log('host:    ' + urlObj.host    );
console.log('hostname:' + urlObj.hostname);
console.log('port:    ' + urlObj.port    );
console.log('pathname:' + urlObj.pathname);
console.log('search:  ' + urlObj.search  );
console.log('searchParams:' + urlObj.searchParams);
console.log('hash:    ' + urlObj.hash    );
```

### Fallback com DOM e tag

Uma alternativa para browsers que não tenham suporte a `URL` é criar uma tag `a`, populando seu `href` com o endereço:

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = document.referrer;
```

De maneira similar ao URL, pode obter "pedaços" do endereço assim:

```
console.log('hostname:', anchor.hostname);
```

Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement

Créditos ao @GuilhermeNascimento, veja mais detalhes nesta postagem:

[pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387408](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387408/70)

### RegEx

Caso alguem precise de soluções para outras arquiteturas ou camadas onde não haja uma solução dedicada como o URL(), esta pesquisa pode ajudar:

[Postagens contendo URL e RegEx no Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+regex+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: Observação: como *fallback* para navegadores mais antigos (se realmente for necessário) você pode usar o `document.createElement('a')`, exemplo: `var anchor = document.createElement('a'); anchor.href = document.referrer; console.log('hostname:', anchor.hostname);`. Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement

Comment: Tentei todos e não exibe a referência apenas do domínio...

Comment: @DivulgueBlogBR você pediu a referencia sem o https: *Qual seria a melhor solução para obter a referencia só **apenas do domínio** ...*, provavelmente você precisa do `urlObj.host` ou do `urlObj.pathname` concatenado com o `urlObj.pathname`,  mas isso não está explicado na resposta, de qualquer jeito, independente do que precisa, o new URL irá fazer o parse e retornar todos valores, com isso você pode concatenar todos que desejar em uma nova string, ignorando as partes que não precisa.

Comment: @DivulgueBlogBR document.referrer só funciona com links que **não** contenham o `noreferrer`. Se tiver noreferrer no link que envia ao seu site o `document.referrer` irá retornar uma string vazia, não é um problema do new URL.

Comment: @guilherme-nascimento Tudo que me passou não sei se estou fazendo certo você não tem algum exemplo dele feito ?

Comment: @DivulgueBlogBR ola. Olha na resposta, o segundo código, aonde está escrito *Aplicado ao caso da pergunta:*, tem um botão chamado `Executar`, clica nele e poderá testar, em qualquer navegador moderno.

Comment: @guilherme-nascimento agora vim eu vi perfeito muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!